# Rails multi page form with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I want to create a way for users to sign themselves up for my service instead of my having to do it.

Currently, the process consists of 3 steps that I have to do through RailsAdmin:

1. Create the Company (acts as the primary key since everything else is tied to it).
2. Create the Location by selecting the previously created Company (giving it a name and unique identifier)
3. Create the users selecting the previously created Company ( using Devise model )

I took a stab at created a nested form, but that didn't work since both Location & User rely on the Company existing first in order to create them.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this feat?  All the gems like Wicked seem to rely on everything being part of one model, not the subsequent models (like User & Location) being dependent on Company existing.

Comment: "I took a stab at created a nested form, but that didn't work since both Location & User rely on the Company existing first in order to create them." You'd better post that code, because nested forms exist specifically to handle the situation you've described.

Comment: I guess you have puzzled it out in your another question, no?

Comment: @Gen ironically, yes... I didn't even know this was related.  LOL